# How to save bash command with a global variable

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Is there any way to save something like

> run-script = some_repetitive_command_you_use

And be able to execute it like

> run-script possible_args

Answer (score 1):

Use a function, for example:

```
doit(){ 
    ls 
    echo "DONE IT $1"
} 

doit once
```

or look at `alias`.

Possibly you could use

```
LS=/usr/bin/ls
$LS /tmp
```

Depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alias` command for that, check this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98782/how-to-run-an-alias-in-a-shell-script) for more information and examples about this topic.